# Rails 3.2 way to count conditional associations without 1+n queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Consider the following models:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I wish to display the Users with their number of posts **in the last 24 hours**.

Obviously a counter_cache would not work here, since I only want to count the records matching the condition `created_at > 24.hours.ago`

In the controller I would have this:

```
@users = User.order(:name)
```

In the view I would have this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Recent posts</th>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.posts.where('created_at > ?', 24.hours.ago).count %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Now this obviously makes a query for every User, causing the dreaded 1+n query problem. Since the count is conditional, adding `.includes(:posts)` in the controller has no effect.

Getting the results in raw SQL would be trivial. What would be the correct *Rails way* to get these results? Preferably in a way to also works in the older 3.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to inner join the posts and let the database count with the help of *group by*. Then you don't need to instantiate the posts. The SQL should then look like:

```
SELECT users.*, count(posts.id) AS number_posts 
  FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN posts
    ON posts.user_id = users.id
    AND posts.created_at > '2016-02-14 08:31:29' 
  GROUP BY users.id
```

Furthermore you can and take advantage of that *select*, which adds the counted posts dynamically as an additional attribute. You only can achieve the extended JOIN condition by using [AREL](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/2.0.2/Arel/Nodes/GreaterThan).
You should push that into a named scope, like:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  scope :with_counted_posts(time=1.day.ago) -> {
    post_table = Post.arel_table
    join = Arel::Nodes::On.new(Arel::Nodes::Equality                            
      .new(post_table[:user_id], self.arel_table[:id])
      .and(Arel::Nodes::GreaterThan.new(post_table[:created_at], time))
    )                                                                           
    joins(Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(post_table, join))              
      .group('users.id')                                               
      .select('users.*, count(posts.id) AS number_posts')  
  }
end
```

Of course there is potential for optimizations and extractions, but for some understanding reasons, I did it more extensive.
Then in the controller:

```
@users = User.with_counted_posts.order(:name)
```

the *users/index.html.erb* view could look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Recent posts</th>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.number_posts %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Although I highly recommend to take advantage of the *render :collection* approach. The *users/index.html.erb* once again:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Recent posts</th>
  </tr>
  <%= render @users %>
</table>
```

and the *users/_user.html.erb* partial:

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.number_posts %></td>
  </tr>
```

I also wrote a blog post about the [*N+1 problem and ARel*](http://www.chrisrolle.com/blog/the-n-1-problem-and-arel)

Comment: Thanks, this seems very clear! I had hoped the code would be a bit cleaner than that Arel chain, but it seems to do the trick! I didn't know that you could call dynamic columns in your select clause as object functions such as `number_posts`. That is very useful information!

Comment: For added bonus, any idea how to combine Arel's `joins`, `group` and `select` function with `includes` ? Lets say I want for every user to get the `number_posts` but also all its IP addresses stored in a seperate table / association? Right now adding an `includes` will overwrite anything in the `select`

Comment: Sure. You're right. *include* let Rails ignore *select*. But that is not AREL specific. That is Rails since ever. If you want that performance stuff, one solution is to add a DB view to your schema, that does all the fancy stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just think 2 solutions:

**Solution 1**: Eager loading first, the select the result with condition:

In controller:

```
@users = User.includes(:posts).order(:name)
```

In view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.posts.to_a.count{ |post| post.created_at > 24.hours.ago } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Solution 2**: Customize the query:

In controller:

```
@users = User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as posts_count
                                      FROM posts
                                      WHERE created_at > '#{24.hours.ago}'
                                      GROUP BY user_id
                                     ) AS temp ON temp.user_id = users.id")
             .order(:name)
             .select('users.*, COALESCE(temp.posts_count, 0) AS posts_count')
```

Explain the query:

- We use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because there are some posts which don't match the `WHERE` clause, so it will be excluded in the subquery, but after `join`, it's `temp.posts_count` will be null
- Use `COALESCE` for `temp.posts_count`, if it is `nil`, it will be treated as `0`

In view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.posts_count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Btw, `1.day.ago = 24.hours.ago`, we may use it instead, since it is a shorter version :|

Comment: Why do you prefer a subquery over an extended JOIN for grouping?

Comment: Join, group by and count seems to be better here than a needless subquery and coalesce call. The first solution will scale very poorly as well. Imagine a user with tens of thousands of posts over the past years. `.includes(:posts)` will retrieve and instantiate them all before iterating over them again in Ruby space and counting only the necessary ones.

Comment: @ChrisDekker: Agree the first solution won't be efficient for scaling, For `Join, group by and count seems to be better here than a needless subquery and coalesce call`, this is simpler but not better in performance, ideally, we always group by and filter first then join, not join first then filter and group by! The cost for joining is always matter